# Error installing tomcat nio plugin for grails 1.3.9

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

I am facing problems while installing tomcat nio(1.3.4) plugin for grails. I am using grails 1.3.9 version.

```
      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

      ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

      :: org.grails.plugins#tomcatnio;1.3.4: not found

      ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Please help or what version of tomcat nio is compatible with grails any solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The old plugins should all have been migrated to the new repo at http://repo.grails.org/ but apparently this one wasn't. You can fix this by adding the old repo in BuildConfig.groovy

```
repositories {
   ...
   grailsRepo "http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins"
}
```

Comment: similar problems occured when upgrading 1.3.9 application grails 2.3.1.. could u please help???

Comment: inconsistent module descriptor file found in 'http://grails.org/plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tags/RELEASE_1_2_7_3/spring-security-core-1.2.7.3.pom': bad organisation: expected='spring' found='org.grails.plugins';

Comment: That's a very old plugin and it probably needs to be updated to work with 2.2+. Try contacting the plugin author.

Comment: You can't - the published zip won't work with newer versions of Grails. But do you really need NIO for development? The regular Tomcat plugin should be fine, and you can configure NIO when you deploy to prod